# Google Play Games forces sign-in

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have an Android app which had Google Play Games working fine. I then updated to the newer version of BaseGameUtils (and google-play-services_lib) about a week ago and have been having trouble with signing in to Play Games Services. When the user is not signed IN (deliberately - by not clicking the sign in button), the sign-in flow for Play Games Services is launched every time that a BaseGameActivity is started. How do I prevent this from happening?

The behaviour I want is that the user has to voluntarily click the sign-in button for the sign-in flow to appear, and then will be automatically signed in every time unless they explicitly sign-out. (This is what used to happen until I updated).

If signed in the behaviour is as normal. The problem is only when the user is not signed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is it was added on purpose by Google. Their FAQ section for BaseGameUtils answers this question.

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/FAQ.txt):

> **[5] I don't like the new "auto sign in" feature of GameHelper. How can
>   I disable it?**
>
> To disable this feature and return to the old behavior, you can edit
>       GameHelper.java and set the DEFAULT_MAX_SIGN_IN_ATTEMPTS constant to 0, or
>       call GameHelper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0) at runtime, before calling
>       GameHelper.setup() (or, correspondingly, from your Activity's onCreate
>       method).

I used `DEFAULT_MAX_SIGN_IN_ATTEMPTS = 0`. Worked perfectly.